# Query for Hotel Reservation System php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making website for Hotel Reservation System. I need help about the query, I was searching through post but i didn't find solution that will work for me.
In my DB i have table booking, with check in and check out date that need to be checked by the query when the user input check in and check out for specified room. Here is my query:

`SELECT * FROM booking WHERE room='$room' and ((checkin>='$cIN' and checkout<='$cOUT' )or(checkin<='$cIN' and checkout>='$cOUT'))`

'$cIN' and '$cOUT' are the inputs from user for check in and check out.
My query in some cases work, lets say for example the room is booked from 15/03/2017 to 20/03/2017, when the new user input 13/03/2017 to 17/03/2017 then the query dont return any results, and the user can book the same room. So in this case we have 2 users in one room in same interval of time. I need to restrict this kind of reservations. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are checking for whether one period completely overlaps the other or vice versa - but of course you also need to take into account the cases where only one of the dates the user enters falls into the already booked period. If you’re having problems figuring out the correct logic, then I’d suggest you scribble the possible cases on a piece of paper - that should help to figure it out.

Comment: If there can be no two bookings on the same date (first guest has booked for until today, so next guest can only book from tomorrow on), then you just need to check if either the start or end date fall into an existing period (including equality on the first/last day)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i think i found solution, your comment helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

To find an overlap we need to search for items where requested checkin is before an existing checkout AND the requested checkout is after the existing checkin.

```
-- Return existing bookings that overlap the requested date range
SELECT * 
FROM booking 
WHERE room = '$room' 
and checkin <= '$cOUT' and checkout >= '$cIN'
```

Simpler than you thought :)

> Note that this query will not allow a new booking to checkin at the same time that a previous booking checked out. If your checkin/out fields do no store time then you will need to alter this logic to use <,> instead of <=,>=

Answer (score 0):

this is my logic, the query is to check your checkin date between the checkin date and the checkout date in the database, also check the checkout date between the checkin date and the checkout date in the database. If there is a database row, your checkin or checkout date is not available.

```
SELECT * FROM reservasi WHERE (
    '$checkin' BETWEEN checkin_date AND checkout_date
    OR '$checkout' BETWEEN checkin_date AND checkout_date)

-->num_rows
```

Additionally, if one room class has many rooms then check first room with the class id. 
If there is no database row, then room is not available.

```
SELECT * FROM room WHERE class_id='$class_id' AND status='available'
```